# How can I extend the java.awt.Color class?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I am writing a graphics library in Java. It will be a front-end for several of the existing Java graphics packages, combining features from java.awt and javax.swing. I'm a teacher and I'm creating this library for my beginning students so they don't have to muck around with a hodge-podge of import statements. I'd also like to provide some additional built-in colors, to augment the limited set that java.awt.Color comes with

I wish to create a Color class that simply extends java.awt.Color. That way, the student doesn't have to import java.awt.Color directly. I've tried this:

```
package graphics;

public class Color extends java.awt.Color
{
}
```

But compiling evokes the error `cannot find symbol - constructor Color()`. Apparently the java.awt.Color class lacks a default constructor and this is causing my class to fail compilation.

Will I just have to bite the bullet and write my own Color class and include some methods to translate between java.awt.Colors and my Colors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, The java.awt.Color does not have a default constructor, so you have to create at least one constructor am make a call to the super constructor:

```
public class Color extends java.awt.Color{
  public Color(int rgb) {
    super(rgb);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would have answered with this example:

```
public class Color extends java.awt.Color {
  public final static Color AZURE = new Color(240,255,255);
  public static Color colorOf(String color) {
    try {
      return (Color)Color.class.getDeclaredField(color).get(null);
    } catch(Exception notAvailable) {
      System.out.println("RGB color " + color + " is not a predefined " +
                         "static color.");
      return null;     
     } 
   } 
 }
```